# Github and Eclipse: not all files are commited

Tags: eclipse, github, commit

I´m using Github in Eclipse, and commiting my changes to it. I have added some files to my project, and I have clicked on Team->"Add to index" in each of them, for them to be commited when I make a commit of the whole project. However, these files are not added to be commited, and when I click in "Commit", they arent´shown in the list of modified files. How can I force them to be commited?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may be confusing the usage of Git wit SVN. In SVN when you add a file to be tracked, updates to the file will always be committed automatically.

In Git, when you add a file to the index, only the current version of that file is recorded. If you subsequently update the file and commit, the new updates won't be included. The solution is to do an "Add to index" on the root of your project right before you commit: the equivalent of `git add .` on the commandline. Make sure your `.gitignore` is set up correctly so you don't commit things you don't intend to.

An equivalent action is to do a `git commit -a`, which automatically adds all files previously in the index and updates any deleted files as well. I believe the equivalent setting in Eclipse (for eGit) would be to **Include selected untracked files** as in the commit settings below.

[image]